# Iteration in R using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to avoid using a for loop and instead use tidyverse for iteration. Specifically, I have a vector of values that I want to loop through a single variable from a data frame to create new variables with a prefix. I've tried using dplyr::across but am unsuccessful when the vector length is >1

Sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

data <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                   y = letters[1:10], 
                   z = LETTERS[1:10])
letter_list <- letters[1:10]

var_naming <- function(dat, list){
  dat %>%
    mutate(!!glue("hx_{list}") := ifelse(y == {list}, 1, 0))
}
```

Code I've tried:

```
**the correct dimensions of the data frame should be 13 variables and 10 observations**

# data_b outputs the correct number of observations but has 40 variables
data_b <- map(letter_list, 
             ~var_naming(data, .x)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

# data_c gives me the correct number of variables but has 100 observations
data_c <- map_df(letter_list,
                 ~var_naming(data, .x))

# error message from data_d when using dplyr::across:
>> Error in `mutate()`:
>> ! Problem while computing `..1 =
  >> across(...)`.
>> Caused by error in `across()`:
>> ! All unnamed arguments must be length 1
>> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

data_d <- data %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols  = y, 
      .fns   = ~ifelse(y == {letter_list}, 1, 0),
      .names = glue("hx_{letter_list}")
  ))
```

```
Desired output:
id y     z      hx_a  hx_b  hx_c  hx_d  hx_e  hx_f  hx_g  hx_h  hx_i  hx_j

1  a     A         1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2  b     B         0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3  c     C         0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4  d     D         0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
5  e     E         0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
6  f     F         0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
7  g     G         0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
8  h     H         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
9  i     I         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
10 j     J         0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @KU99 updated the post to reflect desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with the mutate call, but what you ultimately want is a list of functions (one for each letter in `letter_list`) to pass to `.fns`. Since they are anonymous functions, name them the same as `letter_list` to help with `across` naming the columns

```
myFxs <- map(letter_list, ~function(y) ifelse(y == .x, 1, 0)) %>% 
  setNames(letter_list)
```

For whatever reason, `.names` seemed to be having a problem with the glue character vector (for me anyway). Since the functions are named for the letters they are matching against you can use the `.fn` pronoun to instead to pass a template to `across`

```
data %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols  = y, 
      .fns   = myFxs,
      .names = "hx_{.fn}"
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was so stumped. Appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

The code can be modified

1. Remove the `{}` around the `list` on the rhs of `:=`
2. It may be better to use `transmute` instead of `mutate` as `mutate` returns the whole data by default.
3. Once we get the column binded (`_dfc`) data from `map`, bind the original data with `bind_cols`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
var_naming <- function(dat, list){
  dat %>%
    transmute(!!glue::glue('hx_{list}') := ifelse(y == list, 1, 0))
}
```

NOTE: `list` is a `base R` function to construct `list` data structure.  It may be better to create functions with argument names different than the reserved words or function names already existing.
-testing

```
map_dfc(letter_list, var_naming, dat = data) %>% 
   bind_cols(data, .)
```

-output

```
   id y z hx_a hx_b hx_c hx_d hx_e hx_f hx_g hx_h hx_i hx_j
1   1 a A    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2   2 b B    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
3   3 c C    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4   4 d D    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
5   5 e E    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
6   6 f F    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
7   7 g G    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
8   8 h H    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
9   9 i I    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
10 10 j J    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Anotehr way to get the same results:

```
data %>%
  cbind(model.matrix(~y + 0, .)) %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(., 'y\\B', 'hx_'))

   id y z hx_a hx_b hx_c hx_d hx_e hx_f hx_g hx_h hx_i hx_j
1   1 a A    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
2   2 b B    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
3   3 c C    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
4   4 d D    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
5   5 e E    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
6   6 f F    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
7   7 g G    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
8   8 h H    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
9   9 i I    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
10 10 j J    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

If you only consider those in `letters_list`:

```
data %>%
  mutate( y =factor(y, letter_list)) %>%
  cbind(model.matrix(~y + 0, .) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(paste0('y', letter_list)) %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(., 'y', 'hx_')))
```